# Adding components from right to left

Tags: html, css, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I need to display a list of boxes with maximize, minimize and close button to the bottom right of the screen. The cards should be displayed from bottom right to left. The issue that I am having is cards are getting added from bottom left to right. Say on subsequent clicks of button 1, button 2, button 3 the cards should be in the card3, card2, card1 from bottom because button is clicked first. Here it is happening the other way.

Also I am unable to implement maxmize and minimize function. Cancel operation is working fine.

https://codesandbox.io/s/panel-item-addtion-using-redux-updated-hxmihq?file=/src/components/PanelAdder.jsx

App.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Header from "./src/components/Header";
import Footer from "./src/components/Footer";
import Content from "./src/components/Content";
import Panel from "./src/components/Panel";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const panels = useSelector((state) => state.panel.panelItems);
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Content />
      <Footer />
      <div className="cards-container">
        {panels.map((name) => (
          <Panel key={name} {...{ name }} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

PanelAdder

```
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { addPanel } from "../actions/counterActions";

export default function PanelAdder() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const panels = useSelector((state) => state.panel.panelItems);

  const handleClick = (name) => {
    if (panels.includes(name)) return;
    dispatch(addPanel(name));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => handleClick("Panel 1")}> Add Panel 1</button>
      <button onClick={() => handleClick("Panel 2")}> Add Panel 2</button>
      <button onClick={() => handleClick("Panel 3")}> Add Panel 3</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Panel

```
import React from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {
  faSquareMinus,
  faWindowMaximize,
  faRectangleXmark
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { deletePanel } from "../actions/counterActions";

export default function Panel({ name }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <>
      <div className="card">
        <div className="card-actions">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSquareMinus} />
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faWindowMaximize} />
          <FontAwesomeIcon
            icon={faRectangleXmark}
            onClick={() => dispatch(deletePanel(name))}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="card-body">{name}</div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.cards-container {
      display: flex;
      /* making element one near the other */
      height: 100vh;
      /* setting the height of div to device_height (so we can put them in the end of the page) */
      align-items: flex-end;
      /* aligning the cards to the end of the page */
      justify-content: flex-start;
      /* aligning the cards to the end of the page */
      padding: 1rem;
      /* adding some padding to the end of the page */
      gap: 1rem;
      /* adding some gap between the cards */
    }
```

You just had to put `justify-content: flex-start` here.

**Edit**

Here is how you can max and min the card window.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/panel-item-addtion-using-redux-updated-forked-n5suqd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Just use `useState` to toggle between the two classes. First, set the initial class to be the one you see when you click on the `addPanel` button. Then, you add an `onClick` to the min and max buttons. The min button changes the style of the card to the new style, and the max button sets the style of the card back to the original one.

Comment: Also on click of maximize or minimize card, I need to hide or show the card body, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Try using `useState` to toggle between two classes. Set the initial state to be your card with a display of block or whatever. When you click on the max/min button, set the state to be the second class with the display of none. You can also try visibility, not display.

Comment: Can you help me by ediitng sandbox? I tried with display css, Didnt work as expected

Comment: @li97 Read this article first: https://reactgo.com/react-toggle-class/

Comment: @li97 I think I did what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

```
case "ADD_PANEL":
  return {
    ...state,
    panelItems: [action.payload, ...state.panelItems]
  };
```

Just make the following changes to your reducer and you'll be able to achieve the desired card display.
Instead of adding the new panel to the end of the array, you add it to the start.

Comment: What about maximize and minimize card operation?

Comment: You can use conditional rendering with state variables within the panel component.

For Example:

     const [maximize, setMaximize] = useState(true)

[link](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Comment: Sure. Please explain what the panel should look like minimized and maximized.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/panel-item-addtion-using-redux-updated-forked-29b0iv

Comment: when minimized , it should just have maximize and close button. When maximized, it should have minimze, close and card body

Answer (score 0):

There is several way to do it.

A first one could be to add the new panel as first element instead of the last one in your reducer as Zarish Iqbal did it.

A second one would be to keep the list as is, and to play with the flexbox properties of your `.cards-container`. By using `flex-direction: row-reverse;` and `justify-content: flex-start;`, the items will be displayed in the order you want.

`flex-direction: row-reverse;` make the content go from right to left, and `justify-content: flex-start;` align the content at the start, so on the right.

[More information about flex-direction](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#aa-flex-direction)